# Dense set in $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider $X=C[0,1]$ with its 'sup-norm' topology. Let $$S=\Bigg\{ f \in X: \int_0^1f(x)\;dx \neq 0\Bigg\}$$ How to prove $S$ is dense in $X$ ?

My try:  I know this result " If a subset $A$ is nowhere dense in $X$, then $X \setminus A$ is dense in $X$"

The equivalent statement is " If  $X \setminus A$ is NOT dense in $X$, then $A$ is NOT nowhere dense in $X$.

Here, $X \setminus S$ is a proper closed set, so it is not dense in $X$ and hence by above equivalent statement, $S$ is dense in $X$.

Is this right? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this directly. For any $f\notin X$, it is easy to see that $f+\epsilon\in S$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying! I Know this definition: $S$ is dense in $X$ if every $f \in X$ is either belong to $S$ or a limit point of $S$

Comment: $S$ being dense it means that any open ball $B(f, \epsilon)$ in the sup norm must contain some element of $S$.

Comment: @LDM You can choose a sequence $f+\frac1n\to f$.

Comment: Ok! Whether my argument is right or wrong?

Comment: @EclipseSun: I think, you start with "For any $f \notin S$, it is easy ....." I don't know why you pick $f \notin X$

Comment: If $f\in S$, then we have nothing to do because it's already in the closure of $S$. What we need to consider is $f\notin S$. Your argument is incorrect because what you know is 'not dense $\implies$ complement not nowhere dense', but you are using 'not dense $\implies$ complement dense'.